# x non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

I am trying to use dplyr::summarise() to get a summary of RMSE and correlation values from a table.
The data frame has 2 columns : "observed_value" and "expected_value" which I use to calculate the RMSE and correlation.
However I get the following error

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `RMSE`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i Input `RMSE` is ``%>%`(...)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

```
> rlang::last_error()
<error/dplyr_error>
Problem with `summarise()` input `RMSE`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i Input `RMSE` is ``%>%`(...)`.
Backtrace:
  1. `%>%`(...)
  9. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 10. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context
```

```
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/dplyr_error>
Problem with `summarise()` input `RMSE`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i Input `RMSE` is ``%>%`(...)`.
Backtrace:
     x
  1. +-`%>%`(...)
  2. +-dplyr::summarise(...)
  3. +-dplyr:::summarise.data.frame(...)
  4. | \-dplyr:::summarise_cols(.data, ...)
  5. |   +-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  6. |   \-mask$eval_all_summarise(quo)
  7. +-`%>%`(...)
  8. +-base::mean((observed_values - expected_values)^2)
  9. \-base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 10.   \-dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
```

Please let me know how I can solve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: It would help to see the code you ran and a sample of input that generates the same error.

Comment: The root cause of this error is always the same. Something you expect to be numeric actually isn't numeric. Check the column classes of your data.frame (e.g., using the `str` function).